# NancyFX with Fleck Websockets

Tags: javascript, .net, websocket, nancy

I use NancyFx for a REST API interface in .NET. In addition, I also use Fleck for WebSockets.
When I use Fleck without NancyFx it works but if I use it with NanacyFx more, I get the following error.
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.0.16:9090/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line.
Of course, I also use 2 different ports. Why is that?

many Thanks 

Comment: This behavior occurs only when the server sends the client what.